# RMI plugin for Apache Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there any way to download the RMI plugin for JMeter. I can only get the source code from git but not actually the plugin. I need to test Java webswing application using RMI plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code you can build it, normally Java projects are built by [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), check the project description/readme for the build instructions.

Once you have the plugin:

1. Drop the plugin .jar to "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Drop the plugin dependencies (if any) to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Restart JMeter to pick the plugin up

Also be aware that you can use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) in order to send RMI commands/queries see [Working with JMX](https://groovy-lang.org/jmx.html) article for details so you won't need any plugin.